# Did Max Muller and British interpolate Rig Veda 10.18.7?

Tags: rig-veda, interpolation, sati

Before 20th century, there was another version of the verse below:

> इमा नारीरविधवाः सुपत्नीराञ्जनेन सर्पिषा संविशन्तु |
> अनश्रवो.अनमीवाः सुरत्ना आ रोहन्तु जनयोयोनिम**ग्रे** || (RV 10.18.7)

[The alternate verse is:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sati_(practice))

> इमा नारीरविधवाः सुपत्नीराञ्जनेन सर्पिषा संविशन्तु |
> अनश्रवो.अनमीवाः सुरत्ना आ रोहन्तु जनयोयोनिम**ग्ने** || (RV 10.18.7)

The alternate verse refers to women stepping into fires (yoni **Gagne**).

According to Prof. Wilson, "**Max Muller was the first** to point out the falsification of the text and the change of 'yoni agree into 'yoni agree (womb of fire)"

So can we say modern Rig Veda has been interpolated by the British?